# Grabing first object for each item related to items in an array - DJango

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I have a django project I am working on. I have two tables which are groups and group activities. Groups store information about the group that is created. GroupActivity stores all of the activities that are related to a group. for instance a group called Welcome would be stored in the group table with info about the group. if a member is added to the group there would be a record of the activity in the group activity table. I want to create a system that allows me to grab all of the groups someone is a part of and for each group, grab the last activity that happened for each of the groups that the user is a member of. I tried using two different queries and use two for loops but it is not working at all. Can anyone help me with this.. here is the code I have

Here are the tables:

```
class Group(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 25)
    description = models.CharField(max_length = 250, null=True)
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(User, default=1, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

class GroupActivity(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    group = models.ForeignKey(Group, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    expense = models.ForeignKey(Expense, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    bundle = models.ForeignKey(Bundle, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=200, default='some action')
    host = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    reference = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    category = models.SmallIntegerField(default = 1)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

Here is what i have in the views.py file:

```
# ensure someone is logged in
@login_required(login_url='/login/')
# groups home page
def groups_home(request):
    # grab the logged in user
    user = request.user
    # grab all of the groups you are a member of
    groups = Member.objects.filter(user = user).all()
    # everythin that is going to be passed to the html template
    activities = GroupActivity.ojects.order_by('group').desc()
    parameters = {
        'groups':groups,
        'activities':activities,
    }
    return render(request, 'groups/groups.html', parameters)
```

Here is the html template :

```
      {% for group in groups %}
        <p>
          <a href="{% url 'group_home' group.group.name|slugify group.group.id %}">{{ group.group.name }}</a>
        </p>
      {% endfor %}
```

Example:

```
two groups = Bros and Sisters 
activity = Bros => josh was added
                => steve was added 
                => josh sent steve a message 
           Sisters => jessica added jenny 
                   => jessica added julie 
                   => jessica added stephanie

I want to grab the two groups = Bros and Girls
I want to grab the actviities = josh sent steve a message 
                              = jessica added stephanie
```

I want to display the group and the last activity together like a whatsapp group from the main screen of the applicaiton.

Can anyone help me.

Comment: Hey, @OmarJandali, I was wondering, did any of this answers helped you?

Answer (score 0):

instead of directly querying activities you can use backward relations, use something like this in your template

```
{% for group in groups %}
    <p>
      <a href="{% url 'group_home' group.group.name|slugify group.group.id %}">{{ group.group.name }}</a>
    </p>
    {% for act in group.activity_set.all %}
        {{ act.description }}
    {% endfor %}
  {% endfor %}
```

for more info check [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/queries/#backwards-related-objects) page in django docs.